# Angularfire2 valueChanges() returns data after I deleted it manually in Firebase

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angular6

I am querying a subcollection in Firestore in an Angular6 Web App. On the first run, my function went through, but I was missing some information, so I had to delete it. I deleted the data in the subcollection manually in Firebase.

This is my query:

```
this.inviteSub = this.afs.collection('groups').doc(myGroup).collection<any>('invitations').valueChanges().subscribe(invites => {
    console.log(invites);
});
```

When I execute my function on the client (Chrome) again, the valueChanges returns me the data that actually has been deleted.

I already tried a hard refresh by CTRL+F5 of the website. I also closed the browser. I also tried to unsubscribe when I at ngOnDestroy. But none of my efforts "cleared" up my 'invites'.

Can anyone help me how I "refresh" my browser / function / 'invites'?

UPDATE: 
I still could not figure out what the issue causes, but I changed my App to Angular 6. So, I also changed this in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. In my 'app.module.ts' I had the persistence enabled `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()` and changed it to `AngularFirestoreModule`

Comment: If that could help, I was facing the same "issue" and found that solution was linked to the fact that I explicitly read the value only once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664321/5404186

In case that would help someone later too

Comment: No, as you can see in my function, I am subscribing to an observable. It was the `enablePersistence()` flag, for sure. During testing I deleted data from Firestore manually. But thanks anyway!