# AngularFire doesn't detect changes if persistence is enabled

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm using [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) and have the persistence for offline support enabled in my `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
   AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()
]
```

When my application start, I retrieve the user using `valueChanges()` like the following:

```
const doc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.myCollection.doc<User>(userId);

doc.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user: User) => {
    console.log(user);
}, (err) => {
    console.err(err);
});
```

Strangely to me, if I applies modifications to the database from another source as the application, for example if I log my self into the Google Firestore Console and modify manually a value in the user data, these data won't be fetched.

If I restart the app it will always fetch the locally persisted data and will never notice that the values were changed.

If I remove the persistence, respectively the `enablePersistence()`, the data are correctly fetched.

Do you know what's the reason of the problem?

Should I not use the `valueChanges()` in such case?

Or does this happens because I fetch the value only once (see `take(1)`) and therefore the updated value is never fetched?

Thx in advance for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 minutes later...exactly my problem is the fact that I'm not listening for changes and only reading one value (`take(1)`), respectively the locally persisted one will be read and nothing more afterwards, therefore the updated value won't be fetched

Comment: I had the same problem and I came to the same conclusion after much confusion. Glad to seen im not the only one.

Comment: Maybe in the docs they should specify that live changes are only returned on the 2nd take.

Comment: Happy to hear I was not the only one too ;) I read the documentation another time and just noticed the `fromCache` property, maybe this would have give me a hint (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/offline-data.md). Anyway now I know how it works and always think twice before using `take(1)` anywhere ;)